# How to access DLL methods in Java code using JNA?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

By running `System.loadLibrary("myAPI")`, I verified that the DLL file "myAPI.dll" can be successfully loaded into my Eclipse Java project. Now I need to call methods specified inside this DLL file from my Java code. To do this, I added JNA to my Java project. Then I wrote the below-given code snippet that should be able to get instances of classes `IProject` and `ProjectFactory` (specified in the DLL file).

I still don't understand how to properly implement this with JNA. I checked different threads, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728873/accessing-dll-methods-with-contain-mulitple-classes-using-jna), but the ones I checked don't provide an answer. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;   

public class MyClass {

public interface myAPI extends Library {
    //...
}

void LoadProj() {
    myAPI api = (myAPI) Native.loadLibrary("myAPI",myAPI.class);
    String fileName = "xxx.sp";


    IProject project; // this is wrong but shows what I am trying to do
    try {
        project = ProjectFactory.LoadProject(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Load failure");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Look at the examples on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access, they are pretty concise.

Comment: This is the third question you've posted on the overall topic in an hour.  To learn to do this on your own, you are going to have to develop your ability to work with the documentation and examples available and work through it yourself.  I, for one, am less inclined to help someone if it looks like they are not making their own effort.  Also, "I don't know how to implement" is not a good forum question.  If you need a tutorial, search the web for a tutorial.  If you have a specific question, post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what problem you are facing but as a practice your myAPI interface should declare all the methods verbatim with appropriate [parameter mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access#Mapping_types). I don't see any methods inside your interface.

Please checkout the [this link](http://today.java.net/article/2009/11/11/simplify-native-code-access-jna) as well as the link mentioned above by @Perception

Answer (score 0):

If there are no Java classes or Java source hidden inside this DLL (which would be ... strange), then it will never work this way. You can't instantiate C# classes or use C# interfaces. `MessageBox.Show(` isn't Java either, it is Windows Forms code.