# Accessing a third party DLL using JNA

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to access a 3rd party c++ DLL using JNA. I have looked at the JNA documentation available and some blog for understanding JNA.

But now I am stuck with a problem. The DLL which I have has multiple classes in it. And the functions are defined inside the classes. So there is a hierarchy. How can I access the functions then?

For example I have a DLL named: "abc.dll'. In this dll I have class "pqrs" and in that class there is a function called `xyz()`. I want to access `xyz()` function.

Until now I am able to load abc.dll successfully as following:

```
abc abcDLL = (abc) Native.loadLibrary("abc", abc.class);
```

I have created a interface like this:

```
public interface abc extends Library {
    void xyz();  // this is wrong because "xyz" is not directly "abc.dll" but inside the class "pqrs" which is inside abc.dll
}
```

And like this there are multiple classes inside the dll. I have  searched the web a lot about this. But could not find a solution. I came across to these posts:

- [Accessing DLL methods with contain mulitple classes using JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728873/accessing-dll-methods-with-contain-mulitple-classes-using-jna)
- http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-theory-questions/8865-using-jna-access-export-native-classes.html

But nobody has answered there.

Comment: Unless it is done properly, which it usually isn't, exporting classes across DLL boundaries generally leads to headaches. Please show us at least some of the mangled names of the relevant exports from the DLL, that can at least give us an idea of how the DLL was built. Also please show some of the things you've tried so far.

Comment: Thank you Jason for you reply. Please see my edited post for details. I am sorry but I cannot disclose the original names of dll and functions. I have used alias for them. It should serve the purpose. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So the export name is "abc", totally unmangled, just like that? Not, for example, `?Foo@CXyz@@QAEHH@Z` (as in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppNaiveApproach)? The reason is that the C++ name-mangling scheme is nonstandardized, and if it is used in your DLL exports (which it likely is), then you have very little chance of being able to reliably access even non-class members. As it stands, with the information given, the short answer is: You can't do this unless the classes in the DLL were specifically designed for use with JNI.

Comment: One possible option is to write a JNI-compliant wrapper DLL, in C++, that encapsulates some of the more high-level functionality, or at least provides stubs that act as a bridge interface to your third-party DLL. Then your Java application can use *that* DLL instead.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) :)